# Particles and Boolean Difference

Tags: particles

I am unable to keep particles out of certain areas with Boolean Modifier.
Is this even possible in Blender or is there a work around?
I have tried different orders of the Modifiers with no success.

Dick van den Berg

[image]

Comment: Have you enabled _Use Modifier Stack_ in the particle settings? Because even when the _Particle Modifier_ is placed after the _Boolean Modifier_, this only means the particles don't show up in the "cut out" area, but it is still in some way used by the particle system.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: maybe you should explain the effect you are trying to achieve...e.g. you could make them invisible via shader nodes which would be much faster than a boolean modifier....

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing details, the problem might be that your particles has *Use Modifier Stack* disabled. Even though in the modifiers order the *Boolean Modifier* might be placed above the *ParticleSystem Modifier*, enabling this option ensures that all particles of the given amount under *Emission* > *Number* are emitted in the geometry that remains after cutting out a piece with a boolean operation.

If you look at the following image, without *Use Modifier Stack* enabled, not all particles are distributed randomly in the volume. There is a strange "tower" of particles in the middle, (I guess) these are the ones emitted in the upper (cut out) part of the object. Since there is no volume, they get stacked up in the middle.

[image: particle stack]

If you now enable *Use Modifier Stack*, the "tower" disappears and the volume is filled with all randomly distributed particles, making them look more since there is no stock in a single column anymore.

[image: particles random]

It becomes even more obvious when you use the *Boolean Modifier* with *Union* instead of *Difference*. Without *Use Modifier Stack* enabled the upper volume stays empty:

[image: volume empty]

As soon as you enable *Use Modifier Stack* the upper volume gets filled with particles, too:

[image: volume filled]